# MSI has custom actions involving deprecated nested installations that I want to remove

Tags: vb.net, windows-installer, setup-project

[Orca clearly showing Custom action type 23 - Nested Installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpO8p.png)

[Inspecting in Visual Studio shows no custom actions at all...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeeDh.png)

As part of an update on the MSI I'm working on, one of the tasks is to remove the nested installation, as it is a deprecated method.

I can't seem to find where this SQL2000.msi is coming from

I can't find a way to remove it

Any time I build the MSI the custom actions will be there. It's not good enough to edit the MSI after it has been built, it must be built correctly initially.

What possible ways could the MSI be pulling SQL2000 into the MSI?
I can't seem to find it anywhere on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

You should say what is (or was) being used to build this install because it's not clear where Visual Studio setup projects are involved (your custom action view). To my knowledge, Visual Studio has never generated type 23 custom actions.  So if you are using a VS setup project to build this project, then the only place it can come from is a merge module, so it should be in the imported merge modules. It's probably an MSDE merge module.

The screenshot of Orca and the custom actions has the format that shows they are from a merge module - the custom action name and then the merge module package code, so the MSM you're looking for is the one with packagecode starting A95D...

Comment: Thanks so much for the help Phil.  

I'm using VS setup project.  
So far I have tried to:  
1. Edit the VDPROJ file manually, removing any reference to the   msde.msm and the corresponding entries in the Hierarchy  
2.Removed the MSDE.DLL from the projects solution objects  
3.Removed the MSDE.DLL from the MSI setup project itself (it was excluded anyway)  

Yet I build the MSISetup and the custom action still appears in orca...  
I'm completely lost, there are no remnants of MSDE in the solution anymore. I'm not sure where else I'd need to remove it.

Comment: Could old VB6 .DLLs be causing this issue

Comment: The following msm's remain in the MSI: comcat, oleaut32, COMDLG32, msadodc, msbind, mscomct2, msdbrpts,msdhflxgd, msstdfmt, MSVBVM60, mswinsck, msxml4